# a given point lies inside or outside a polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I was trying this question and found a solution :

Draw a horizontal line to the right of each point and extend it to infinity

> 1) Count the number of times the line intersects with polygon edges.
>   2) A point is inside the polygon if either count of intersections is odd or
>      point lies on an edge of polygon.  If none of the conditions is true, then 
>      point lies outside.
>   [image: polygon]

But i think there is a simple solution to this :

> for(all sides in same order)
>       find vector product of the 3 points (given point and end points of each side)

`if all products are > or < 0 : point lies inside polygon or on boundary

else outside`

isn't my solution better and efficient ?
is there another simpler algorithm than this ?

Comment: Isn't this really a question for the Mathematics forum? http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does your algorithm take into account the possible intermediate concavity of the polygon? (vertex internal angle > 270 or 300 degrees)

Comment: i think it should be `independent` of concavity or convexity . we just have to see the `sign` of cross product . The important thing is to move in same direction (clockwise or counter-clockwise).

Comment: What do you mean by vector product of 3 points? (vector(A->B)) x vector(P)?

Comment: area of triangle formed by the 3 points : `(x2 - x1)*(y3 - y1)-(y2 - y1)*(x3 - x1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed algorithm using cross product check only works for convex polygons. For non-convex polygon it is quite easy to find an example where it does not work. Try any of the points `c`, `d` or `e` in the polygon given.

Comment: ok i think it should be : `sum of all angles = +- 360 degree`

Comment: Yes, sum of angles should work, but it does not seem to be more efficient than raycasting as there are trigonometric functions involved. Also it would have problems with rounding/precision if number of edges is high.

Comment: so what algo should be used other than this?

Comment: Use raycasting as in the solution you have found.

Comment: can you please provide me with a useful link for raycasting ?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you suggest only works for convex polygons & in fact used for calculation of the convex hull but would fail for concave which is again proved by correctness of convex hull algorithm.

Another way to use this algorithm is to divide your polygon into convex polygons and then apply the algorithm on the divided parts to see if the point is inside anyone of them

[Polygon triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)